# CRITICAL_SECTION and avoiding including windows.h?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an interface declared like this:

```
    #if defined _WIN32 || _WIN64
        typedef CRITICAL_SECTION MutexHandle;
    #else
        typedef pthread_mutex_t MutexHandle;
    #endif

    class IMutex
    {
    public:
        enum MutexState
        {
            UNLOCKED = 0,
            LOCKED
        };

        virtual ~IMutex() { }

        virtual int32_t Lock() = 0;
        virtual int32_t Unlock() = 0;

        virtual const MutexState& GetMutexState() const = 0;
        virtual MutexHandle& GetMutexHandle() = 0;
    };
```

The problem is, I need to include windows.h for CRITICAL_SECTION definition;

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

but dosn't this cause possible header include problems with others using the interface?

How can I declare my typedef without having to include the whole windows.h?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this would cause possible header include problems?  Why do you undef `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`?

Comment: @MooingDuck, without `#define NOMINMAX` (or something like that) it's almost bound to cause problems somewhere.

Comment: In Windows build, include `<windows.h>` without hesitation. Basically all you need is to define full class inside your `#if`, not just handle. And you are free to choose how exactly you are going to implement it: sections, mutexes whatsoever.

Comment: @RomanR.: if the code that includes this header isn't expecting the Windows SDK, including it is undesirable.

Comment: How do you plan on using this particular method? Is there some other method somewhere else that also takes MutexHandle? Also: why are you returning a *reference* to an enum for GetMutexState() rather than just a plain copy of the current value?

Answer (score 9):

The typical way to prevent the implementation details from leaking into other code is to use the Pimpl Idiom.  The idea is to make your class simply contain a pointer to the real implementation.  Since the real implementation lives in a .cpp file, it can include whatever it needs without polluting the namespace of the users of the class.

In the header file:

```
#include <memory>  // for std::unique_ptr

class Mutex {
  public:
    Mutex();
    ~Mutex();
    void Lock();
    // ...
  private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_pimpl;
};
```

Then in the implementation (.cpp) class:

```
#include <windows.h>  // nobody else sees this

class Mutex::Impl {
  public:
    Impl() {
      ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }
    ~Impl() {
      ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }

    void Lock() {
      ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }

    // etc.

  private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;
};

// This maps the externally visible Mutex methods to the
// ones in the Implementation.
Mutex::Mutex() : m_pimpl(new Mutex::Impl()) {}
Mutex::~Mutex() {}
void Mutex::Lock() { m_pimpl->Lock(); }
```

You could put the whole implementation into #ifdef blocks, or in separate .cpp files (e.g., mutex_win.cpp, mutex_posix.cpp, etc.) and just use the correct one for your type of build.

In general, the Pimpl Idiom requires extra pointer dereferencing, but so does your virtual method solution.

Comment: Great! But you don't even need the pimpl idiom for this. The CPP file is *always* separate from the header file, so as long as you don't write everything in the header, you can separate these easily.

Comment: How would you implement the `GetMutexHandle` function (which has to return a pointer to the underlying `CRITICAL_SECTION`) in this model?

Comment: The trick is to keep the OS-specific stuff out of the API.  You don't really want a `GetMutexHandle` method because it would have to expose the OS-specific underlying type.  If you absolutely must have a way to get the handle, then you have to make another wrapper class (e.g., MutexHandle) that plays the same PIMPL game to keep the OS-specifics isolated to the implementation file.  GetMutexHandle would then return a MutexHandle rather than the actual OS type.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Without Pimpl, the header file would still need a private member that's a CRITICAL_SECTION or pthread_mutex_t, which leaks OS-specific details into every translation unit that includes the header.

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer slightly coarser separation of code paths, maybe like this:

```
struct WinMutex;
struct PTMutex;

#ifdef WIN32

typedef WinMutex Mutex;

#include <windows.h> // or whatever

struct WinMutex
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    void lock()   { /* lock it */ }
    void unlock() { /* unlock it */ }
};

#else

typedef PTMutex Mutex;

#include <pthread.h>

struct PTMutex
{
    pthread_mutex_t m;
    PTMutex() { pthread_mutex_init(&m); }
    ~PTMutex() { pthread_mutex_destroy(&m); }
    void lock() { pthread_mutex_lock(&m); }
    void unlock() { pthread_mutex_unlock(&m); }
}

#endif
```

That way, each individual class is easy enough to inspect and refactor, and you still get platform-dependent implementations. Or, if you find a pthreads implementation for Windows, you could even have both simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much how I do it too, except that I just name the classes the same to start with, no typedefs just to rename classes. Sometimes I even put the #ifdef into the function bodies, especially when the classes have platform-independent code as well, or if I just feel like it (it certainly helps to ensure that the interfaces are the same, without having to go virtual. It does tend to mess up readability to some extent, though).

Comment: This doesn't really address the OPs concern, though; the code that includes this header will still be unexpectedly acquiring the entire Windows SDK.

Comment: exactly; how can I get around this?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: If you need a Windows API mutex, you need to include the Windows API headers... I don't think you can avoid that, nor is it a problem. The lean-and-mean macro that you have should be sufficient. Are you experiencing an actual problem?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think the point is that this header might be included by code that is never actually going to call `GetMutexHandle` and wants the OS-specific implementation details to remain hidden.  (See my answer for how I would solve this; you could probably improve on it!)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Depending on what the mutex type actually is, you might get away with just extracting the type itself, so you can define your class, and then separate the implementation of lock and unlock into its own translation unit, so you only need to include the full header there. But that would rob you of inlinablility, which is probably a shame.

Comment: The WinMutex name is misleading, since a Windows Mutex is distinct from a CRITICAL_SECTION (though both are implementations of the mutex concept).

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Oh OK, I didn't know. I'd put the primitive mutex type in the class, not some wrapper, so to get the same behaviour on each platform.

Answer (score 2):

I think the underlying issue is that you're exposing an operating-system-specific type to what might be non-operating-specific code.

One solution, depending on your needs, might be to exclude the `GetMutexHandle` function from the `IMutex` interface but include it in two subinterfaces, `IMutexWin32` and `IMutexPosix` say.  You could declare the `IMutexWin32` interface only for code that specifically requested it, and require such code to include `Windows.h`.  Any code that's going to actually make use of `GetMutexHandle` on Windows will need `Windows.h` anyway.

Alternatively, you could make the `GetMutexHandle` return a separate interface class, with OS-specific subinterfaces.

A minor variant of the same theme would be to detect whether Windows.h has been included (`#ifdef _WINDOWS_`) or not and use this to decide whether or not to declare the Windows-specific subinterface.

The easiest (but ugliest) solution of all would be to make `GetMutexHandle` return a pointer to void and trust the caller to cast it properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to completely avoid the header dependency on windows.h, you need to forward declare `CRITICAL_SECTION` in such a way as to match the existing declaration in windows.h. You'll need to make sure this works for the version of windows.h you are using, but this should work:

```
extern "C"
{
    typedef struct _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION;
    typedef RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION CRITICAL_SECTION;
}
```